# Matlab error when opening "An error was encountered while saving the command history"

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu

I installed matlab on my linux machine but on a media drive `/media/d/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b` but when I open Matlab I get the below error, so if anyone could please advise how to solve this:

```
An error was encountered while saving the command history
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/userA/.matlab/R2014b/History.xml (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistoryCollection$CommandSaver.run(AltHistoryCollection.java:1212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Seems like a permission issue. Can you access directory /home/userA/.matlab/R2014b/? If directory is not present, you should create it manually. Also, check if you have permission to create new files in the said directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change permissions of the directory ~/.matlab so that I can write into it. I used the following command in terminal and the problem was resolved:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .matlab
```